# What language is better for serial programming and working with MySQL database? Python? Realbasic?

Tags: python, mysql, serial-port, realbasic

I'm doing a project that is serial based and has to update a database when a barcode is being read. Which programming language has better tools for working with a MySQl database and Serial communication. I debating right now between python and realbasic.

Comment: What may be noteworthy is that most barcode readers can act as a keyboard so chances are you won't need to write serial communication routines yourself...

Comment: By readers you mean scanners?

Comment: @OMG Ponies I might as well try fortran if that's the case. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is a general purpose language with tremendous community support and a "batteries-included" philosophy that leads to simple-designs that focus on the business problem at hand. It is a good choice for a wide variety of projects.

The only reasons not to choose Python would be:

1. You (or your team) have greater experience in another general purpose language with good library and community support.
2. You have a particular problem that is handled best by a specialty language that was written with that sort of problem in mind.

The only thing I know about RealBASIC is that I hadn't heard of it until now, so it's a lock that it doesn't have quite the community of Python. (Exhibit A: 60,000 Python questions on SO, only 49 RealBASIC questions.) And if it is a derivative of BASIC, it would be not be a specialty language.

Python seems a clear choice here, unless it means learning a new language, and you are proficient with RealBASIC.

Comment: thank you for this. These are both languages that I am unfamiliar with. I know java and many web languages. Thank you for your answer and you will get the check button. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to imagine that Realbasic is a better choice than Python for *any* project.

Comment: Haha you too huh? A co-worker of mine suggested it but and I started researching it. It seemed very hard to make a console program since it seems like a more of a desktop approach.

Comment: What if you needed to develop a cross-platform desktop (i.e. non-browser) application ?